# Dojo stateful transform for checkboxes

Tags: checkbox, dojo, stateful

So for a dijit/form/CheckBox, value is either a string for true, or false. This causes a problem for things in my data source which are Y/N values. I've tried do a checkbox subclass to override _setValueAttr and _getValueAttr to return/set Y/N properly but no luck.

I also considered linking my mvc "at" function with a transform to convert the data, but apparently this only works on widgets that have format/parse functions (checkboxes do not).

So, how else might I go about linking a checkbox to my stateful with a Y for checked and a N for unchecked?

Answer (score 0):

if you made your own checkbox, extending the standard one and making it stateful, then you could override _valueGetter and _valueSetter functions to do the mapping Y/N - true/false

Normally this should be enough, but dangerous in the case of widget functions calling this.get("value");